# Antimatch with Regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I search for a regex pattern, which shouldn't match a group but everything else.
Following regex pattern works basicly:

```
index\.php\?page=(?:.*)&tagID=([0-9]+)$
```

But the `.*` should not match *TaggedObjects*.

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: TaggedObjects? Is that the string it should not match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(?:.*)` is unnecessary - you're not grouping anything, so `.*` means exactly the same. But that's not the answer to your question.

To match any string that does not *contain* another predefined string (say `TaggedObjects`), use

```
(?:(?!TaggedObjects).)*
```

In your example,

```
index\.php\?page=(?:(?!TaggedObjects).)*&tagID=([0-9]+)$
```

will match

```
index.php?page=blahblah&tagID=1234
```

and will not match

```
index.php?page=blahTaggedObjectsblah&tagID=1234
```

---

If you do want to allow that match and only exclude the exact string `TaggedObjects`, then use

```
index\.php\?page=(?!TaggedObjects&tagID=([0-9]+)$).*&tagID=([0-9]+)$
```

Comment: it could be just `(?!TaggedObjects).*` according to your first point.

Comment: @SilentGhost: No, the repetition is outside of the group (in order to apply the negative lookahead at every position that follows). An alternative to `(?:(?!TaggedObjects).)*` would be `(?!.*TaggedObjects).*`. though.

Comment: I dont see a point in putting a negative lookahead (?!) inside a passive group (?:) Because the negative lookahead wont be captured anyway. Why do you put a single "." inside the passive group?  why not .*?

Comment: @Jass: See my previous comment - it ensures that the lookahead is applied at every position in the match, not just the beginning. But `(?!.*TaggedExpression)` works, too (as I wrote above).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I think you mean you want to fail the match if the string contains an occurence of 'TaggedObjects'

```
index\.php\?page=(?!.*TaggedObjects).*&tagID=([0-9]+)$
```