# Regex to find a word then exclude specific words from consideration

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex which I use to find a word:

`(?<=\s)([\w\@\-]+)(?=\s)`

I want to further modify this regex to exclude a list of words e.g. do not match if the word is 'cat' or 'dog'.

How do I accomodate the regex to achieve this?

Comment: This one is similar: [I have a PHP regEx, how do add a condition for the number of characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13994553/367456), even specifying a minimum length what qualifies a word.

Comment: @hakre It doesn't seem that similar to me?!

Comment: Oh it is, the answer you accepted uses the same regex features. ;) - It just does the length check as well, which you don't have here (well you have one or more characters to form a word).

Comment: @hakre Ok, but the answer to that doesn't answer my question. You'll have to be a Regex ninja to draw the correlation between the two, and a regex ninja am I not, ergo my question.

Comment: I wrote similar, not identical. It's just a link in case someone stumbles over this question and is looking for alternatives. It's not saying that your question would be wrong or anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\b(?!(?:dog|cat)\b)([\w@-]+)\b
```

Here if you want to match word start/end with `@`

```
(?<=\s)(?!(?:dog|cat)(?=\s))([\w\@\-]+)(?=\s)
```

Comment: +1, but not equivalent to @ChuckUgwuh's regex - it won't match an entire "word" if it ends in `@` or `-` (unlikely), and it *will* match at the start/end of the string (where his solution won't).

Comment: @TimPietzcker yeah u right..he can change \b to lookaround assertion to match @ at the start/end of string

Comment: @slier Thanks. The lookaround assertion for @, how would I pull that off?!